# How to add layers in Azure Maps

Tags: javascript, c#, azure-maps

I am using Azure Maps and I would like to toggle between two layers on click of a button.

Two layers that I am using are HTML marker and Symbol layers.

Currently , I am able to display both these layers on page load in javascript. However , I would like to toggle these layers on click of a button.

Edit --

Basically we would like a add layers similar to the pic so that we can toggle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `visible` option. When you want to toggle the state of one layer, get the layer options using `getOptions`, then check the visible option and reverse its value, then set it on the layer again. For example:

`layer.setOptions({ visible: !layer.getOptions().visible });`

Comment: Thank you for the answer , this gave me good hint , however I would like to toggle between layers. similar to the pic mentioned in google maps. Basically I have added a button click for another layer and on page load but everytime I click on button it refreshes.

Comment: To make sure I understand, the layers are your own data layers correct. If so, you could use a variable to keep track of which layer is currently active, then when you switch to another layer (button click), hide the previous layer, show the new layer and update the variable to point to the new layer. The UI control is basically a customized radio button collection. If you are looking for something that is more pre-built, take a look at this module: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-layer-legend